# Is it OK to ask questions on SO about "questionable" developer practices? (e.g. private iOS APIs)

Tags: discussion

Is it acceptable on SO to ask a question related to a potentially "questionable" or "disapproved" development practice or strategy?

Specifically, I'd like to ask a question related to use of private iOS APIs for an app **that I do not plan to distribute** and only plan to use **on my own devices for personal use**. I would of course possibly share the app as open source, but obviously any app that uses private APIs will not be allowed on the App Store. (You could imagine this to be a situation where a jailbreaker wants to ask a question on SO about their jailbreak app. Or maybe GBA4IOS developers.)

The reason I ask is that, as I understand it, technically use of, or even gaining knowledge of, the iOS private APIs is considered against Apple's agreements with developers. I'm not sure of the legal issues surrounding this, but I do know that the headers for iOS private APIs are easily found online (much to Apple's chagrin, I'm sure) - it's a matter of whether it's allowed to discuss such headers and their use in private applications on SO. Does this open SO to issues due to the possibly open discussion of use of APIs which Apple specifically forbids using?

I don't see anything obvious that specifically prohibits asking such questions, but I wanted to be sure. (I may have missed something also.)

Comment: As long as you're not discussing break any of those rules, I don't really see the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is [not on Stack Overflow to police developer agreements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94465/should-moderators-enforce-ndas-for-software-vendors), codes of conduct, or third-party terms and conditions. All we can judge is whether something is a good programming question or not. When it comes to legal agreements on things like NDAs, that's [between the developer and whatever company issued it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49009/as-an-ipad-iphone-ipod-touch-developer-what-cant-i-ask-or-answer-on-stack-over/49366#49366). Stack Overflow and the developers here aren't responsible for any potential breaches someone else might make.

Any flags asking for this content to be closed or deleted will be declined. If the company themselves wishes to file a DMCA takedown request, there is a form they can fill out to do this, but moderators and community members will not honor these requests.

All that said, there are plenty of questions about private APIs here. They're not exactly illegal to work with, particularly for personal projects. If you are going to ask about the use of a private API, state that it is private upfront and that you know what that entails. This simply avoids people wasting their time by trying to steer you towards non-private APIs that don't do what you want.